# Google API invalid_grant / bad_request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, google-oauth

Using python 3.6, requests==2.22.0

Trying to use the Google API, in particular [mobile and desktop apps flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp)

I am able to generate an auth code by using this url:

```
url = (
    'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?'
    'scope=email%20profile&'
    'response_type=code&'
    'redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&'
    'client_id={client_id}&'
    'access_type=offline'.format(
        redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
        client_id=client_id,
    )
)
```

The redirect_uri I am using (for now) is simply `https://google.com`, and it is registered in the developer app I generated, in the `Authorized redirect URIs` section `and` in the `Authorized domains` section under the `OAuth consent settings` page/tab.

Once I paste the produced url in the browser - I get a code that I can extract and use to make the next call, which currently fails.

I made sure to replace `"%2F"` with `"/"` (when using Firefox).

Next, I am generating the data, and making the call to replace the code with the tokens:

```
data = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'code': code,
    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
}
url = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token'

response = requests.post(
    url,
    data=data,
    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },

print(response)
print(response.json())
```

The output:

```
<Response [400]>
{'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Bad Request'}
```

Comment: Invalid grant normally means the client id / secret / code you are sending is invalid.

Comment: Your'e right @DaImTo - it was the code - I was cleaning it improperly

Answer (score 1):

It's a two year-old issue but just for the sake of those came in here looking for an answer. I run into the same problem @camelBack did, the way I solve was kind of simple. I delete the credentials and run the authorization flow again. With new credentials.storage in place the problem went away.
More info @ https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

An additional note for those struggling with the auth flow, one thing I realized after a lot of testing is that you need to run outside Jupyter Notebook. Open a terminal and run Python natively with the script. It should work.

Comment: why can't you run it in a notebook? Seems like you could do that in steps within the notebook, no?

Comment: As far as I understand, that's a limitation.  The fact is that when you run on notebook it does not start the flow process.